# Use AST module to mutate and delete assignment/function calls

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, mutation

For example if I wanted to change greater than to less than or equal to I have successfully executed:

```
def visit_Gt(self, node):
    new_node = ast.GtE()
    return ast.copy_location(new_node, node)
```

How would I visit/detect an assignment operation (`=`) and a function call `()` and simply delete them? I'm reading through the AST documentation and I can't find a way to visit the assignment or function call classes and then return nothing.

An example of what I'm seeking for assignment operations:

```
print("Start")
x = 5
print("End")
```

Becomes:

```
print("Start")

print("End")
```

And an example of what I'm seeking for deleting function calls:

```
 print("Start")
 my_function_call(Args)
 print("End")
```

Becomes

```
print("Start")

print("End")
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, and include an example of the kind of code you are trying to edit? By removing the assignment, should the whole right-hand expression go, or just the target list and `=`? And by removing the call, do you mean you want to find assignments that involve a function call, or remove *all calls*, so `some_function()` becomes `some_function`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`ast.NodeTransformer()` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) to mutate an existing AST tree:

```
import ast

class RemoveAssignments(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        return None

    def visit_AugAssign(self, node):
        return None

new_tree = RemoveAssignments().visit(old_tree)
```

The above class returns `None` to completely remove the node from the input tree. The `Assign` and `AugAssign` nodes contain the whole assignment statement, so the expression producing the result, and the target list (1 or more names to assign the result to).

This means that the above will turn

```
print('Start!')
foo = 'bar'
foo += 'eggs'
print('Done!')
```

into

```
print('Start!')


print('Done!')
```

If you need to make more fine-grained decisions, look at the child nodes of the assignment, either directly, or by passing the child nodes to `self.visit()` to have the transformer further call `visit_*` hooks for them if they exist:

```
class RemoveFunctionCallAssignments(NodeTransformer):
    """Remove assignments of the form "target = name()", so a single name being called

    The target list size plays no role.

    """
    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.value, ast.Call) and isinstance(node.value.func, ast.Name):
            return None
        return node
```

Here, we only return `None` if the value side of the assignment (the expression on the right-hand side) is a `Call` node that is applied to a straight-forward `Name` node.  Returning the original node object passed in means that it'll not be replaced.

To replace *top-level* function calls (so those without an assignment or further expressions), look at `Expr` nodes; these are expression *statements*, not just expressions that are part of some other construct. If you have a `Expr` node with a `Call`, you can remove it:

```
def visit_Expr(self, node):
    # stand-alone call to a single name is to be removed
    if isinstance(node.value, ast.Call) and isinstance(node.value.func, ast.Name):
        return None
    return node
```

Also see the excellent [*Green Tree Snakes* documentation](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/), which [covers working on the AST tree](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manipulating.html) with further examples.

Comment: I apologize for my question lacking in detail. You absolutely nailed the answer, thank you.

Comment: @MMM: you can always add to the question even though you got your answer, to help future visitors understand if they have the same problem to solve.

Comment: I will do that now. I misread the last part of your answer and will include more detail about what I meant in deleting function calls. One moment as I type it up. If you could add to your answer that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @MMM: added, I'm sure you can mix and match these tools to come up with the right combination now. :-)

Comment: Quick question: If I am visiting an Assign, how do I see the targets/val? I've tried printing self.targets and self.val but that doesn't seem to work. For example if I had x = 5, how would I find the variable name x?